# Cryptography in disaster recovery

Tags: cryptography

If cryptography certificates are used in production environment and the production environment is replicated to disaster recovery, would the same certificates be valid for the disaster recovery environment?

Comment: Ekhm... yes?  If you use the right configuration and the right type of certificate, for example?  This is way too broad there are at least 57,786 possible ways of a configuration being a production environment and at least 452 different way on configuring certificates in each (the certificates will not work in at least one of those configurations).  It is much better to provide a scenario that can be replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have the certificate key pair (public and private), any computer can act as identified by the the certificate CN (common name). This is suppose to match the FQDN of your service, or else many browser will fail the authentication on the client side without even checking the signatures.

Provided that you use a reverse proxy (or DNS changes) to switch from production to recovery server, the transition can appear seamless to the client.